# Can't change value in array php

Tags: php, arrays, json, foreach

```
{
    "available":18,
    "bind":0,
    "info":"",
    "hours_definitions":[
        {
            "value":"21:40"
        },
        {
            "value":"22:50"
        }
    ],
    "hours":{
        "21:40":{
            "available":1,
            "bind":0,
            "info":"",
            "notes":"",
            "price":3000,
            "promo":0,
            "status":"available"
        },
        "22:50":{
            "available":1,
            "bind":0,
            "info":"",
            "notes":"",
            "price":3000,
            "promo":0,
            "status":"available"
        }
    },
    "notes":"",
    "price":2000,
    "promo":0,
    "status":"available"
}
```

I have JSON array (**$dataar**), where I need to change "available" to 0 where "hours" array 21:40.

I am trying to use foreach:

```
$dataar1 = json_decode($dataar, true);
$dataar2 = $dataar1['hours'];
$hour = "21:40";
foreach ($dataar2 as $key => $entry) {
     if ($key == $hour) {
        $dataar2[$key]['available'] = 0;
    }
}
```

And I get `$dataar2[$key]['available'] = 0`, but when I am trying to `json_encode` it back, i see available:1 again.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Add the code you use to encode it back to JSON - I think you might not be encoding the correct variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You aren't changing the actual variable per-say, you're just assigning it to a new variable and changing that. This will work:

```
$dataar1 = json_decode($dataar, true);

foreach($dataar1['hours'] as $key => &$val) {
    if($key == '21:40') {
        $val['available'] = 0;
    }
}
```

<sup>*The above example is using [`PHP's passing by-reference`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php) to modify the original array.*</sup>

[**`Example`**](https://eval.in/246403)

Answer (score 1):

You are only changing $dataar2, which is a new variable and no relation to the original.  Try this instead:

```
$dataar1 = json_decode($dataar, true);
$hour = "21:40";
foreach ($dataar1['hours'] as $key => $entry) {
     if ($key == $hour) {
        $dataar1['hours'][$key]['available'] = 0;
    }
}
$dataar = json_encode($dataar1);
```